# Object has no atribute

Tags: python, pandas

I have this problem

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_value'

AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-176-25558b9cd48f> in <module>

      3     visitor_team = row["Visitor Team"]

      4     row["HomeLastWin"] = won_last[home_team]

----> 5     dataset.set_value(index, "HomeLastWin", won_last[home_team])
```

**My code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

won_last=defaultdict(int)
dataset["HomeLastWin"]=0
dataset["VisitorLastWin"]=0

for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
    home_team = row["Home Team"]
    visitor_team = row["Visitor Team"]

    row["HomeLastWin"] = won_last[home_team]

    dataset.set_value(index, "HomeLastWin", won_last[home_team])
    dataset.set_value(index, "VisitorLastWin", won_last[visitor_team])

    won_last[home_team]=int(row["HomeWin"])
    won_last[visitor_team]=1-int(row["HomeWin"])
```

Comment: Looks like maybe this is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html)?  They suggest using `at` or `iat` instead

Comment: Can you help me, i haven't resolved it. Isn't working

Comment: I answered, but you next time you should post what you have tried and show what "isn't working", this helps to narrow down the issue faster : D

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:  looks like `set_value` is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html), so you need to use a different method.  They suggest using `at`:

```
dataset.at[index, "HomeLastWin"] = won_last[home_team]
```

Or you could also use `loc`:

```
dataset.loc[index, "HomeLastWin"] = won_last[home_team]
```